# How to split String with "\" as a delimiter? and also how to replace "\" into ":"?

Tags: java, android, replace, split

Hi I would like to know what should I put in order to split the string into parts using "\" as a delimiter?

The String returned by the server will be as shown below

`String test ="\\ipAddress\FolderA\InnerFolderA\abc.mp4";` << this one give me error ,thus i have to put in another "\",

```
String test ="\\ipAddress\\FolderA\\InnerFolderA\\abc.mp4";

String parts[] = test.split("\\");
        String part0 = parts[0];
        String part1 = parts[1];
        String part2 = parts[2];
```

and when I run it, it gives me error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Unexpected internal error near index 1.

Also when I tried replacing the String using this line of code to replace the "\" as in

```
String output = test.replaceAll("\\", ":");
```

it also give me error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "\\ipAddress\\FolderA\\InnerFolderA\\abc.mp4";
        String output = test.replaceAll("\\\\", ":");
        System.out.println(output);

        String parts[] = test.split("\\\\");
        String part0 = parts[0];
        String part1 = parts[1];
        String part2 = parts[2];
        System.out.println(part0);
        System.out.println(part1);
        System.out.println(part2);

    }
```

**output**

```
:ipAddress:FolderA:InnerFolderA:abc.mp4

ipAddress
FolderA
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use "\\" as the argument,not "\". Very glad to help you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test ="\\ipAddress\\FolderA\\InnerFolderA\\abc.mp4";

    String parts[] = test.split("\\\\");
            String part0 = parts[0];
            String part1 = parts[1];
            String part2 = parts[2];
            System.out.println(part1);
}
```